# Is it possible to loose data or different data is present on different key in Ignite Cache?

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I am using Ignite cluster on 3 Ignite nodes. In which, the cache which is operating has `CacheAtomicityMode` as `Atomic` and `CacheMode` as `PARTITIONED`.

Is it possible to lose data or use different data that is present on a different key?

Note: The data loading happens on the server side. It is possible that the same data with multiple objects will load on all the servers at same time

Cache Config:

```
CacheConfiguration<String, JsonObject> cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration<>();
cacheConfig.setName("CACHE");
cacheConfig.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
cacheConfig.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC );
cacheConfig.setReadThrough(true);
cacheConfig.setBackups(2);
cacheConfig.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(ObjectLoader.class));
cacheConfig.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_ASYNC);
IgniteCache<String, JsonObject> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two nodes go down before it's finished copying the data to both backups, you might lose some data. You can change that by using the FULL_SYNC Write Synchronisation Mode.

(Also worth noting: if you want to have all your data on all nodes, you can use the REPLICATED Cache Mode.)

Comment: Yes, I already changed cache mode to REPLICATED but before when I was using PARTITIONED mode the duplicated values were present on different key. means value of A present on key A and B both.